# Positioning image bug while zooming

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a custom zoom functionality for an image on my site. There is a small bug that I can't seem to work through related to this functionality.

My code uses two images:

```
<div id="img-anchor-1" class="thumb-show active_zoom">
  <img id="product_img" 
  src="http://s7d9.scene7.com/is/image/AmericanApparel/ah3260ws_deeppeacock? 
  defaultImage=/notavail&amp;$ProductZoom$">

  <img class="zoom" 
  src="http://s7d9.scene7.com/is/image/AmericanApparel/ah3260ws_deeppeacock? 
  defaultImage=/notavail&amp;$ProductZoom$" style="width: 100%; opacity: 0; 
  left: 0px; top: 0px;">

</div>
```

Then CSS/jQuery to handle the zooming when clicking the image.

```
var src = $('.thumb-show').find('img').attr("src");
$('.thumb-show').append('<img class="zoom hidden" src="'+src+'" >');
var zoomed_in = false;

$(document.body).on('click', '.thumb-show' ,function(){
  if(zoomed_in == false)
  {
    $(this).addClass("active_zoom");
    $(this).children(".zoom").removeClass("hidden");
    zoomed_in = true;
    $(this).mousemove(function(event){
      var offset = $(this).offset();
      var left = event.pageX - offset.left;
      var top = event.pageY - offset.top;

      $(this).find('.zoom').css({
        width: '200%',
        opacity: 1,
        left: -left,
        top: -top
      })
    });
  }
  else if(zoomed_in == true){
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var left = event.pageX - offset.left;
    var top = event.pageY - offset.top;
    $(this).removeClass("active_zoom");
    $(this).children(".zoom").addClass("hidden");
    zoomed_in = false;
    $(this).find('.zoom').css({
      width: '100%',
      opacity: 1,
      left: -left,
      top: -top
    })
  }
});

$('.thumb-show').mouseleave(function(){
   $(this).find('.zoom').css({
     width: '100%',
     opacity: 0,
     left: 0,
     top: 0
   })
 });
```

This all works perfectly except for one bug.

When a user clicks the image to zoom (does not move the mouse), clicks to un-zoom, (again does not move the mouse), then clicks zoom again, the second (zoomed) image appears to the left of the container.

I have tried adjusting the CSS and jQuery, but I'm not able to fix this issue.

If anyone has any suggestions, it would greatly be appreciated.

Here's a working example in CodePen: 
https://codepen.io/EricBellDesigns/pen/PXaZLg

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your only setting **width: '200%'** on **mousemove** and if you click again without moving the mouse it keep remaining **width:100%;** because mouse is never moved.This will solve your problem,

```
 if(zoomed_in == false)
  {
    $(this).addClass("active_zoom");
    $(this).children(".zoom").removeClass("hidden");
    zoomed_in = true;

    $(this).find('.zoom').css({
        width: '200%',
        opacity: 1,
    })

    $(this).mousemove(function(event){
      var offset = $(this).offset();
      var left = event.pageX - offset.left;
      var top = event.pageY - offset.top;
      $(this).find('.zoom').css({
        width: '200%',
        opacity: 1,
        left: -left,
        top: -top
      })
    });

  }
```

Working [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/REJRPr).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your insight and help! I'm going to give this a shot shortly.

Comment: Sure let me know 